# SUM range of cells after performing VLOOKUP on each cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, vlookup, named-ranges

I have an workbook the keeps track of points in an F1 championship.

One sheet contains a named data range for the points system like so:

[image: points system used for each race]

This data range is called `chmp_pts_tbl` (championship points table).

As you can see, finishing first place in a race is worth 25pts, 2nd is worth 18pts, and so on.

On the other worksheet, I have a table of race results (inc some sample data):

[image]

I've 'hard coded' the data in the image for illustration purposes, to show how it should work.

Using the image as an example, for each row, I want the value in the `PTS` cell to be the sum of all the driver's race results.

Somehow, I need to integrate VLOOKUP with the values in the championship table race results.

Again, looking at my example, `Lewis Hamilton` has 68pts because he's had 2x 1st place finishes, and 1x 2nd place (25 + 25 + 18).

If I just `SUM` his race results, I'll get `4` (1 + 1 + 2), but what I actually want it to do is swap out the race finishing position, for the number of points that position is worth, THEN add them all up.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel split the named range into two so you can use a formula like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,E2:L2,B:B))
```

[image]

Comment: That is absolute sex lol.  Seriously though, thanks.  Awesome answer +1